# Django annotate first occurrence of x in sorted queryset

Tags: django

I have a queryset where the owner's objects are displayed first then objects not owned by them are followed.

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    sort=Case(
        When(owner=self.request.user, then=0),
        default=1, output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('sort', 'name')
```

Now if that produced the following, how can I annotate the first occurrence that the owner is not the request user so that `obj_list[2]['first_occurrence'] = True`?

```
obj_list = [
    {'owner': 1, 'name': 'B', 'sort': 0},
    {'owner': 1, 'name': 'D', 'sort': 0},
    {'owner': 6, 'name': 'A', 'sort': 1},
    ...
]
```

Alternatively is there a way to get the first occurrence (**without regrouping**) where `request.user != obj.owner` so that I can insert an extra table row?

```
{% for obj in obj_list %}
    {% if obj.first_occurrence %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is typically something I'd do in the view, not in the template. Once you have `obj_list`, get the first occurrence (`next(obj for obj in obj_list if obj['sort'] == 1)`) and pass it as **additional** variable to the template so you can test `if obj == first_occurence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in the query itself, annotations work **per row** so it's afaik impossible to annotate a row based on its occurrence in the rest of the query.

But this is typically something I'd do in the view, not in the template. Once you have `obj_list`, get the first occurrence:

```
first_occurence = next(obj for obj in obj_list if obj['sort'] == 1)
```

and pass it as additional variable to the template so you can test if `obj == first_occurence`.